# How to access a HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> in JSTL using dynamic keys?

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, jstl

I want to access a `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>` by key in a  loop in JSTL, but the method I tried does not work.

There are two methods which I have tried, and while the first one works, it defeats the purpose of using a HashMap. I want to be able to access the value by using the key directly.

```
<%
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> LocationLevels = 
levelManagementBean.getLocationLevels((Integer) 
session.getAttribute("NodeId"), (String) 
session.getAttribute("NodeName"));

pageContext.setAttribute("LocationLevels", LocationLevels);
%>

<c:forEach items="${LocationLevels}" var="elem">
    <c:if test="${elem.key == 9}">
        <c:forEach items="${elem.value}" var="levs">
            <c:out value="${levs}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>

<br>

<c:set var="temp" value="9"/>
<c:forEach var="elem" items="${LocationLevels[temp]}">
    <c:out value="${elem}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

LocationLevels is a HashMap returned from a Bean function. The first two lines of the code are in scriptlet tags (I know it isn't the best practice, but because of some constraints, I am trying to keep the HashMap getting part same while converting all the other parts of the JSP page to JSTL). The function getLocationLevels returns a HashMap in the required format, this is guaranteed (because I had a Java code in scriptlets earlier, which worked).

Suppose I want to access the ArrayList stored in the HashMap corresponsing to the key 9. The first `<c:forEach>` loop works, but the second one doesn't, and I can't figure out why.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What error you are getting can you pose here

Comment: The loop before the `<br>` tag works fine. It displays the elements of the arraylist corresponsing to that key. But the loop after `<br>` tag does not work, it displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, the ${entry.value} is actually a List, thus you need to iterate over it as well:

```
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${LocationLevels}">
        <c:if test="${entry.key == '9'}">
            <c:out value="${entry.value}"/>
            <c:set var="tempList" value="${entry.value}"/>
        </c:if>                                      
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach var="elem" items='${tempList}'>
        <c:out value="${elem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear in the original question, but I was asking about the `<c:forEach>` loop after the `<br>` tag. That one isn't working.

Comment: can you try with ${map['key']}, single quote.
like   <c:forEach var="elem" items="${LocationLevels['temp']}">

Comment: could you please try as above ans i have updated it recently , Its working for me

Comment: It might work, but it defeats the purpose of using a HashMap in the first place. Looping through all keys to find the one I'm looking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Nikhil what map internally does while you call map.get(key)? 
And use of map is your requirement and it make does not make sense if every key has same list , but if its differs than of course it does make sense

Comment: If I understand correctly, Map.get(key) first calculates hash of the key, then calculates the index where that key is stored (which depend on the hash), and then directly fetches the value at that index (in whatever internal data structure is being used). It might not make that big of a difference for me since I have a small number of keys, but I think it sure is faster than doing it by iterating over all keys.